# Errors after running next build immediately after creating nextjs project with npx create-next-app@latest

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

I am trying to create a simple app with Next-js and then build it in order to get static HTML/JS files that I can add inside a larger hosted website.

### Create Next-js using npx-create-next-app@latest

So, I started by creating a new Next-js project using the command `npx create-next-app@latest`.

In case it may be related to the error, these were the options I chose when prompted:

```
What is your project named? my-app
Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? [No] / Yes 
Would you like to use ESLint with this project? [No] / Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS with this project? [No] / Yes
Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? No / [Yes]
Use App Router (recommended)? No / [Yes]
Would you like to customize the default import alias? [No] / Yes
```

### Confirm auto-generated boilerplate works

Then running `npm run dev` and checking http://localhost:3000 I saw the default boilerplate Next-js running no problem

### Problem when running next build

Now, I try to run `next build` to see if I can get some static files on the /out folder. Because the link here says it can be done.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

**But it fails with the following errors:**

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
```

Note that I have not changed any of the default files generated by nextjs so far or added any of my own.

I tried to search around the folders looking to find for references for `useContext` or `useMemo` and couldn't find any. I am also not sure of where is the 404 and 500 page code being generated.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

I'm sorry if this question feels basic, I have not much experience with NextJS. I have been looking around for similar errors and in some cases it seems that it was an error installing or adding react to the project. But I can see react inside the node_modules folder.